# How do I check if a controller's action has a routed URL in CakePHP?

Tags: url, cakephp, routes

Is there a CakePHP method when requested a URL/link to be created (using a router array) that will respond with whether a matching pattern, and hence, friendly URL can be returned for the request?

**Example:** No routes matching `array('controller' => 'thing', 'action' => 'show', 'abc' => 'def')` will return the 'default' *controller/action/params:values* structure of `/thing/show/abc:def`.

I would like to know if a URL request was formed by a route. Otherwise the URL, and therefore the controller's action, should not be publicly accessible.

**Note:**

I have removed the `require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';` line from **routes.php**, so there should not be the 'default' matching of any controller/action, yet using the *url* method still returns the 'default' structured URL. It would be more convenient to use this result as a test for if a URL request is valid/publicly available.

I am aware that *CakeRoute*, which is used by *Router*, has the `match()` method which returns false on an unmatched URL after testing against all connected routes, but I can't figure out how to access this functionality from *Router*.

Comment: I think this may be an [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) . What are you _really_ trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks @swiecki, I have reworded the question to hopefully avoid this.